# Merge objects have array, and keep both value of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 objects, and combine them by using `jQuery.extend` function.

```
john_5_years_ago = {
    name: "john",
    company: "google",
    languages: ["c++", "java"]
}

john_now = {
    name: "john",
    company: "facebook",
    nation: "US",
    languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"]
}

$.extend(true, {}, john_5_years_ago, john_now)
```

It returns result like this:

```
{
    name: "john",
    company: "facebook",
    nation: "US",
    languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"]
}
```

But I expected the value of `languages` array should be merged, not be overwritten. And the expected result should be like this:

```
{
    name: "john",
    company: "facebook",
    nation: "US",
    languages: ["python", "java", "javascript", "c++"]
}
```

I'll appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.extend()` will merge objects and deep will also work. But while merging size of the array **wont change and it will not find distinct values**. It will substitute those values at the indexes, that is what it does (I have included the describing demo below).

For more details refer the [**document**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) as well as [jQuery code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L297)

*So this function will not give solution to your case, you should write a custom function (like my solution section).*

And to store the deeply merged result in output you should specify it in the second parameter like `$.extend(true, john_now, john_5_years_ago);`

```js
var john_5_years_ago = {
  name: "john",
  company: "google",
  languages: ["c++", "javascript", "c"],
  extra: {
    aExtra: "aExtra1 value",
    bExtra: "bExtra1 value",
    cExtra: "cExtra1 value"
  }
}

var john_now = {
  name: "john",
  company: "facebook",
  nation: "US",
  languages: ["python", "java", "c", "javascript"],
  extra: {
    aExtra: "aExtra2 value",
    cExtra: "cExtra2 value",
    zExtra: "zExtra2 value"
  }
}

$.extend(true, john_now, john_5_years_ago);
console.log(john_now);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

## Solution:

Use custom function to loop through those 2 objects for merging two objects deeply.

**Note:-**

I have also added `deep` parameter to specify whether the object should be copied in child levels or not.

```js
var john_5_years_ago = {
  name: "john",
  company: "google",
  languages: ["c++", "java"],
  extra: {aExtra:"aExtra1 value", bExtra: "bExtra1 value", cExtra: "cExtra1 value"}
}

var john_now = {
  name: "john",
  company: "facebook",
  nation: "US",
  languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"],
  extra: {aExtra:"aExtra2 value", cExtra: "cExtra2 value", zExtra: "zExtra2 value"}
}

function extend(object1, object2, deep) {
  $.each(object1, function(i, key) {
    if (object1[i] instanceof Array && object2[i] instanceof Array) {
      $.each(object2[i], function(j) {
        if (object1[i].indexOf(object2[i][j]) == -1)
          object1[i].push(object2[i][j])
      });
    }else if(deep === true && object1[i].constructor==={}.constructor && object2[i].constructor==={}.constructor){
    //console.log('{}');
      extend(object1[i], object2[i]);
    } else if(object2[i] != undefined) {
      object1[i] = object2[i];
    }
  });
  $.each(object2, function(j) {
    if (object1[j] === undefined)
      object1[j] = object2[j];
  });
}
extend(john_now, john_5_years_ago, true);
console.log(john_now);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation gave me a clue. And I found other solution, a bit tricky one. I re-implement function `jQuery.extend ` by adding `copy = _.union(src, copy)` after line 243. That's it, `jQuery.extend` works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html>
>  <html>
>  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
>  <body>
>
>    <p>Click the button to join two arrays.</p>
>
>     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
>
>    <p id="demo"></p>
>
>   <script>
>     function myFunction() {
>
>     john_5_years_ago = {
>      name: "john",
>      company: "google",
>      languages: ["c++", "java"]
>     }
>
>  john_now = {
>    name: "john",
>    company: "facebook",
>   nation: "US",
>   languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"]
>  }
>
>  var children  = $.extend(true, {}, john_5_years_ago, john_now);
>   console.log(children)
>   children = merge_array(children.languages, john_5_years_ago.languages);
>   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = children;
> }
>
> function merge_array(array1, array2) {
>   var result_array = [];
>   var arr = array1.concat(array2);
>   var len = arr.length;
>   var assoc = {};
>     while(len--) {
>       var item = arr[len];
>         if(!assoc[item]) 
>        { 
>          result_array.unshift(item);
>          assoc[item] = true;
>       }
>    }
>
>   return result_array;
>  } </script>
>
> </body>
>  </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could write this in Plain JS:

```js
var old = {
    name: "john",
    company: "google",
    languages: ["c++", "java"]
}

var now = {
    name: "john",
    company: "facebook",
    nation: "US",
    languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"]
}

Object.keys(old).forEach(function(prop) {
  if(now[prop] != undefined) {
    if(now["languages"] instanceof Array && old[prop] instanceof Array) {
      old[prop].forEach(function(item) {
        if(now[prop].indexOf(item) == -1) {
          now[prop].push(item);
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    now[prop] = old[prop];
  }
});

console.log(now);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/6c5kgwcw/

```js
var john_5_years_ago = {
    name: "john",
    company: "google",
    languages: ["c++", "java"]
}

var john_now = {
    name: "john",
    company: "facebook",
    nation: "US",
    languages: ["python", "java", "javascript"]
}

$.each(john_now, function(i, key){
  if(i === 'languages'){
    $.each(john_5_years_ago[i], function(j){
      if(john_now[i].indexOf(john_5_years_ago[i][j]) == -1)
     john_now[i].push(john_5_years_ago[i][j]) 
    });
  }
});

console.log(john_now);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've used `jQuery .each` method & loop through the new object.

Hope this will help you.